# CentOS 5.8 server, installed Web Server vs yum install httpd

Tags: centos, apache-http-server, httpd

I would like to know, what is the different between, the build-in CentOS server web server vs I install manual with `yum install httpd`

I am new in CentOS. I just installed my CentOS 5.8 Server with Web Server checked.
With some Google Search with LAMP installation, they listed with `yum install httpd`

I had check inside

> /etc/init.d/

already had `httpd`

I try to run `yum install httpd http-devel`

It shows not yet installed.

What will happen if I install yum version? What should I do? What is the best practise? Should I remove the Web Server install by default with CentOS?

My goal is install LAMP (PHP v5.2.17).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTPd *is* the default web server that installs with CentOS.

http://mirror.centos.org/centos/5/os/i386/repodata/comps.xml:

```
<group>
  <id>web-server</id>
  <name>Web Server</name>
  <packagelist>
     ...
    <packagereq type="mandatory">httpd</packagereq>
 ...
```

Comment: ya, so what if I install with yum install httpd, will it conflict? what is the best practise to setup it, due to I need to install PHP v 5.2.17

Comment: There is no conflict, it's **the same damn package**. PHP 5.2.17 isn't available in the repos though; only 5.1.6 and 5.3.3 can be installed.

Comment: Oh! that's great. I have this confusion because, when I enter `yum install http-d` it was asking me new installation. So I have the a thought it might conflict with original package. Thanks!

Comment: btw, how can I check the apache version? I tried `/etc/init.d/httpd -v` but not working. please help

Comment: That's the initscript. The binary is in `/usr/bin`.

Comment: inside `/usr/bin` I couldn't find any httpd or apache. Can I have the full command also, thanks for helping. I really new in Linux environment. I checked inside `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`, also not found.

Comment: ok, I got it, it is in `usr/sbin/httpd -v`. Thanks!